# How to preserve copy of diagram (in PNG) that is inserted to PowerPoint?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

1. In Draw.io save your drawing as PNG (or export it as PNG with the option "Include a copy of my diagram").
2. In PowerPoint insert the image and save the slide deck. close PowerPoint.
3. Upon reopening the PowerPoint slide deck, click on the image and select "Save as Picture".

The image saved from PowerPoint won't contain the drawing anymore and therefore the drawing can't be opened in Draw.io anymore.

Is there a way to preserve the drawing in PowerPoint?

Notes:

1. Draw.io stores the drawing XML in `zTxT` field of PNG, according to [this blog](https://www.diagrams.net/blog/xml-in-png).
2. In PowerPoint setting the following preference doesn't help either: File => Options => Advanced => Image Size and Quality => "Do not compress images in file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerPoint:

1. select the image
2. right click => Save as Picture...
3. in the "Save As Picture" dialog
   click the tiny arrow aside the "Save" button => Save Original Picture

This saves the original image with the embedded diagram in it.